# Parsing csv file and writing rows to file according to relative size

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, csv, export-to-csv

I have a long list of weather variables across time that I have already filtered to remove those that don't conform to certain criteria. For example, all of the data points only lie between 11am (11) and 5pm (17pm). The data that lies between 11 and 17 o clock represents a single event, and not every day contains an event. I am trying to determine which days exhibited an event. I know that a new event is taking place every a value in the time (HH24) column is a lower value than the one that preceded it. E.g. if a value of 16 (5pm) is followed by an 11,12,13,14 or 15, then I know that the data has progressed to a new day and event.

The code I am trying to write will take the row that contains this last value (e.g. 17) and write it to a file and will then write the next row. In this way, the new csv file will contain the starting time (and other information) and ending time of every event. I assume I will need to use a for command, but I am not sure how to do this with csv writer for this particular challenge. The outline of my code is present below, with the sections I need help with following the #

```
import csv

with open("weather_out_2000_2006_time_filtered_and_speed_filtered.csv", "rb") as input, open("X:\weatherresults\seabreezeevents.csv", "wb") as wanted:
    reader = csv.DictReader(input, delimiter=",", skipinitialspace=True)
    fieldnames = reader.fieldnames
    writer_wanted = csv.DictWriter(wanted, fieldnames, delimiter=",")
    writer_wanted.writeheader()

    for line_number, row in enumerate(reader):
        try:
            if float(row["HH24"]) < #the value in the subsequent row:
                writer_wanted.writerow(row) # and also write subsequent row
        except:
            print "Failed to parse line", line_number
            print row
```

My data file looks like this. I have shown a transition of HH24 from a high value to low value so you can see what I mean.

```
hd,Station Number,Year Month Day Hours Minutes in YYYY,MM,DD,HH24,MI format in Local time,Year Month Day Hours Minutes in YYYY,MM,DD,HH24,MI format in Local standard time,Year Month Day Hours Minutes in YYYY,MM,DD,HH24,MI format in Universal coordinated time,Precipitation since last (AWS) observation in mm,Quality of precipitation since last (AWS) observation value,Air Temperature in degrees Celsius,Quality of air temperature,Air temperature (1-minute maximum) in degrees Celsius,Quality of air temperature (1-minute maximum),Air temperature (1-minute minimum) in degrees Celsius,Quality of air temperature (1-minute minimum),Wet bulb temperature in degrees Celsius,Quality of Wet bulb temperature,Wet bulb temperature (1 minute maximum) in degrees Celsius,Quality of wet bulb temperature (1 minute maximum),Wet bulb temperature (1 minute minimum) in degrees Celsius,Quality of wet bulb temperature (1 minute minimum),Dew point temperature in degrees Celsius,Quality of dew point temperature,Dew point temperature (1-minute maximum) in degrees Celsius,Quality of Dew point Temperature (1-minute maximum),Dew point temperature (1 minute minimum) in degrees Celsius,Quality of Dew point Temperature (1 minute minimum),Relative humidity in percentage %,Quality of relative humidity,Relative humidity (1 minute maximum) in percentage %,Quality of relative humidity (1 minute maximum),Relative humidity (1 minute minimum) in percentage %,Quality of Relative humidity (1 minute minimum),Wind (1 minute) speed in km/h,Wind (1 minute) speed quality,Minimum wind speed (over 1 minute) in km/h,Minimum wind speed (over 1 minute) quality,Wind (1 minute) direction in degrees true,Wind (1 minute) direction quality,Standard deviation of wind (1 minute),Standard deviation of wind (1 minute) direction quality,Maximum wind gust (over 1 minute) in km/h,Maximum wind gust (over 1 minute) quality,Visibility (automatic - one minute data) in km,Quality of visibility (automatic - one minute data),Mean sea level pressure in hPa,Quality of mean sea level pressure,Station level pressure in hPa,Quality of station level pressure,QNH pressure in hPa,Quality of QNH pressure,#
    hd,40842,2000,3,22,13,40,2000,3,22,13,40,2000,3,22,13,40,0,N,20.4,N,20.5,N,20.4,N,20.2,N,20.2,N,20.1,N,20.1,N,20.1,N,20,N,98,N,,N,,N,9,N,8,N,18,N,7,N,11,N,,N,1013.3,N,1012.2,N,1013.3,N,#
    hd,40842,2000,3,22,13,47,2000,3,22,13,47,2000,3,22,13,47,0,N,20.5,N,20.5,N,20.5,N,20.2,N,20.2,N,20.2,N,20.1,N,20.1,N,20,N,97,N,,N,,N,4,N,0,N,56,N,75,N,5,N,,N,1013.2,N,1012.1,N,1013.2,N,#
    hd,40842,2000,3,23,11,0,2000,3,23,11,0,2000,3,23,11,0,0,N,23.4,N,23.4,N,23.3,N,21.3,N,21.4,N,21.3,N,20.2,N,20.3,N,20.2,N,82,N,,N,,N,8,N,5,N,66,N,2,N,9,N,,N,1013.6,N,1012.5,N,1013.6,N,#
    hd,40842,2000,3,23,11,1,2000,3,23,11,1,2000,3,23,11,1,0,N,23.4,N,23.4,N,23.4,N,21.4,N,21.4,N,21.3,N,20.3,N,20.3,N,20.2,N,82,N,,N,,N,8,N,5,N,68,N,3,N,9,N,,N,1013.6,N,1012.5,N,1013.6,N,#
```

Comment: Show sample output csv you want to get from your input.

Comment: I don't think it will work as you want.  You need to look at the date as well.  `E.g. if a value of 16 (5pm) is followed by an 11,12,13,14 or 15, then I know that the data has progressed to a new day and event`.  True enough, but if a value of 11 is followed by a 12 and then a 13, you don't know whether these are new events or not, since if they're on the same day they are not, but on different days they are.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to write a row whenever the date changes, so I think it's best that you create a date variable for comparison.
(and I mentioned in my comment why just comparing the "HH24" value won't work for determining when you're reached a new date)

It's much easier to track and write out the *previous* row (since you've already processed it), rather than the *subsequent* row, so that's how you should think about proceeding.
Something like the following should help (untested):

```
...
import datetime
prev_row = None
for line_number, row in enumerate(reader):
    try:
        dt = datetime.date(year=row["Year"], month=row["Month"], day=row["day"])
        if prev_row is not None and dt > prev_row['dt']:
            writer_wanted.writerow(prev_row['row'])
            writer_wanted.writerow(row)
        prev_row = {'row':row, 'dt':dt}
    except:
        print "Failed to parse line", line_number
        print row
```

**EDIT:**

The first part of this line in **your** program:

```
with open("weather_out_2000_2006_time_filtered_and_speed_filtered.csv", "rb") as input
```

opens the named `.csv` file for input (since the `mode` is 'rb' - [docs here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)).

The next part of that same line:

```
open("X:\weatherresults\seabreezeevents.csv", "wb") as wanted
```

opens that named file for output ('wb' mode) - see the same reference as above.

At this point, the variable names, `input`, and `wanted` now, both refer to objects of the [file type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects).

Your program next uses the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module to read the file in a specific way that helps assists with parsing out comma-delimted text files; and assigns that reference to the `reader` variable.
Similarly, it assigns the variable, `writer_wanted` to a `csv.DictWriter`, which will help with formatting when writing out lines to your output file, referenced by `wanted`.

After that, one line at a time is read in by:

```
for line_number, row in enumerate(reader):
```

and one line at a time would be written out by:

```
writer_wanted.writerow(row)
```

If you want more details than that, your best bet is to go through some Python tutorials (Google is your friend).

Comment: Thanks Gerrat, that certainly makes sense. I'm not sure in this example how I am reading in my original csv file and to what file I am writing it to? Forgive the noob questions, I'm pretty new to python.

Comment: As in, how do I import the file for the code you have described above? And how do I write it out to a csv?

Comment: This isn't really a tutorial site, or place for extended discussion, but I will explain a little more about the code for you.